# Can humans smell if a book has been opened?

Tags: smell

From a [story about Richard Feynman](http://pospapendix.blogspot.com/2008/04/richard-feynman-stories-part-three.html):

> Then I looked at the bookshelf and
>   said, "Those books you haven't looked
>   at for a while, right? This time, when
>   I go out, take one book off the shelf,
>   and just open it--that's all--and
>   close it again; then put it back."
>
> So I went out again, she took a book,
>   opened it and closed it, and put it
>   back. I came in--and nothing to it! It
>   was easy. You just smell the books.
>   It's hard to explain, because we're
>   not used to saying things about it.
>   You put each book up to your nose and
>   sniff a few times, and you can tell.
>   It's very different. A book that's
>   been standing there a while has a dry
>   uninteresting kind of smell. But when
>   a hand has touched it, there's a
>   dampness and a smell that's very
>   distinct

Is this true?

Comment: It's easier than picking a vault's lock in Los Alamos

Comment: I don't have evidence, but try it - when you open a book which hasn't been looked at for a while you let air get to it. Makes perfect sense that that will allow dust and other particles to come out, and for some of the moisture in the air to get at the pages. Haven't tried Los Alamos yet @belisarius :-)

Comment: Out of curiosity, was "she" wearing perfume?

Comment: Might be one of those cases where there's another, simple, trick to it, but to make it more interesting you claim it's something more subtle. :)

Comment: The difference is not, I think, that the book was opened, but that it was handled by a human hand.  That would probably leave smell traces that could be identified by a sufficiently sensitive nose.  Feynman was testing whether the human nose was incapable of fine sensing like that, or if humans just didn't bother with it.

Comment: @Lager In his book Feynman describes how he picked the locks from almost every vault in Los Alamos atomic facility. I don't see why he would lie on this innocent one ... :)

Comment: Eh, yeah, books that has been standing in a shelf for a while smell dry and dusty. I'm sure this is easier to spot in my undusted bookshelves. :-)

Comment: @David I think it does make a difference. Paper decays and the act of opening a book will probably scatter decayed paper molecules. Given that only very few molecules are needed to trigger our sense of smell this seems a plausible cause.

Comment: Maybe they used different smelling paper in the ol' days?

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, we know that the mechanism exists for this to be achieved: dogs can already do this and can distinguish which and where human scents have been left.

In the case with Feynman he is claiming a similar mechanism, getting people to touch books that haven't been touched in a while so there is no residual scent and being able to find which book has been touched by comparing a person's scent to a scent left on a particular book. He has a slightly easier job to a dog that is picking up the scent of a stranger running through the bush.

I also have [other anecdotes](http://physics.divinechildhighschool.org/Home/summer-reading/testing-bloodhounds) on the net where people have claimed Richard continued to do this as a party trick to non-believers, so it appears it was not a one-off which he refused to do again.

> Years later, when Feynman was first at Caltech, he went to a party at
>   Professor Bacher's house. He was talking to a group of people from
>   Caltech when the story of smelling the bottles came up. Nobody
>   believed a word of it. So, Feynman decided to perform the experiment
>   again. He left the room and had three people touch three different
>   books to see if he could identify who touched which book. He came
>   back, smelled everyone's hands, and then smelled the books. He found
>   the three books correctly and got one person wrong. Yet, the people
>   still did not believe him.

There is this research paper (extract only) which indicates smells can be picked up between humans, but there results were only better in chance between relatives:

> The basis of olfactory signatures mediating human kin recognition was
>   investigated in two experiments. The odors of mothers and offspring
>   were correctly matched (by subjects unfamiliar with the stimulus
>   individuals) at a greater than chance frequency. In contrast, subjects
>   were not able reliably to match the odors of husbands and wives. These
>   data support the hypotheses that characteristic individuals odors are
>   genetically mediated and that kin recognition should be facilitated by
>   the similarity of such familiar odors among close relatives.

The only other evidence I could find of it being possible is this passage from Darwin's ["Descent of Man and Selection in Relation to Sex"](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=_X79kDtFCGcC&pg=PA567&lpg=PA567&dq=%22The%20account%20given%20by%20Humboldt%20of%20the%20power%20of%20smell%20possessed%20by%20the%20natives%20of%20South%20America%20is%20well%20known%22&source=bl&ots=VhR1Q_jVHV&sig=SkqwQscdcw9ziU8r_RMgiJjb7cY&hl=en&ei=WA9CTsHWA-Xa0QGssO33BQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CBgQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22The%20account%20given%20by%20Humboldt%20of%20the%20power%20of%20smell%20possessed%20by%20the%20natives%20of%20South%20America%20is%20well%20known%22&f=false):

> “(36. The account given by Humboldt of the power of smell possessed by
>   the natives of South America is well known, and has been confirmed by
>   others. M. Houzeau ('Etudes sur les Facultes Mentales,' etc., tom. i.
>   1872, p. 91) asserts that he repeatedly made experiments, and proved
>   that Negroes and Indians could recognise persons in the dark by their
>   odour.”

Note [this article](http://www.thelogics.org/thelogicsolfactorysmell.html) seems to go into Olfactory Perception in excrutiating detail, if you want go through it in fine detail I suggest this would be the place to do it.